# Algorithm W and monomorphic type coercion

Tags: type-inference, type-theory, type-variables, monomorphism

I'm trying to write my own type inference algorithm for a toy language, but I'm running into a wall - I think algorithm W can only be used for excessively general types.

Here are the expressions:

```
Expr ::= EAbs String Expr
       | EApp Expr Expr
       | EVar String
       | ELit
       | EConc Expr Expr
```

The typing rules are straightforward - we proceed to use type variables for abstraction and application. Here are all possible types:

```
Type ::= TVar String
       | TFun Type Type
       | TMono
```

As you might have guessed, `ELit : TMono`, and more specifically, `EConc :: TMono → TMono → TMono`.

My issue comes from doing the actual type inference. When recursing down an expression structure, the general technique when seeing an `EAbs` is to generate a fresh type variable representing the newly bound variable, replace any occurrences of typing in our context with the `(String : TVar fresh)` judgment, then continue down the expression.

Now, when I hit `EConc`, I was thinking about taking the same approach - replace the *free expression variables* of the sub expressions with `TMon` in the context, then type-infer the sub expressions, and take the most-general unifier of the two results as the main substitution to return. However, when I try this with an expression like `EAbs "x" $ EConc ELit (EVar "x")`, I get the incorrect `TFun (TVar "fresh") TMon`.

Comment: I'm unsure if manipulating the context is the correct approach. Maybe take the most general unifier of the untainted sub expressions with `TMon` itself?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mgu` to coerce sub-expressions. If you directly manipulate the context to affect sub expressions, you don't know how that affects earlier types. Use `mgu` to get the substitution that unifies sub expressions to `TMon`, then compose that substitution in the result.